# Javascript - DocuSign for Salesforce Custom Button

Tags: javascript, docusign

Getting the following error when clicking a custom button I created: 
*A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: Invalid or unexpected token*

My code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var 
CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var 
CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var 
SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES=''; 
//*************************************************// 

var CES=’Please sign this [Company]’; 
var LA='0'; 
var DST='213eba34-766e-41e9-9ca0-c79f9aa094ed'; 

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href = 
"/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID= 
{!Lead.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+" 
&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+" 
&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+" 
&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+" 
&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES; 
//*******************************************//
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in line:

`var CES = ’Please sign this[Company]’`;

The inverted comma used is different. It should be

`var CES = 'Please sign this[Company]'`;

Apart from the above error, there were ENTER presses in the last line which were causing the issues. The below code works fine

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

```
var RC = '';
var RSL = '';
var RSRO = '';
var RROS = '';
var CCRM = '';
var CCTM = '';
var
    CCNM = '';
var CRCL = '';
var CRL = '';
var OCO = '';
var DST = '';
var LA = '';
var
    CEM = '';
var CES = '';
var STB = '';
var SSB = '';
var SES = '';
var SEM = '';
var
    SRS = '';
var SCS = '';
var RES = '';

var CES = 'Please sign this [Company]';
var LA = '0';
var DST = '213eba34-766e-41e9-9ca0-c79f9aa094ed';

window.location.href =
    "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Lead.Id}&RC=" + RC + "&RSL=" + RSL + "&RSRO=" + RSRO + "&RROS=" + RROS + "&CCRM=" + CCRM + "&CCTM=" + CCTM + "&CRCL=" + CRCL + "&CRL=" + CRL + "&OCO=" + OCO + "&DST=" + DST + "&CCNM=" + CCNM + "&LA=" + LA + "&CEM=" + CEM + "&CES=" + CES + "&SRS=" + SRS + "&STB=" + STB + "&SSB=" + SSB + "&SES=" + SES + "&SEM=" + SEM + "&SRS=" + SRS + "&SCS=" + SCS + "&RES=" + RES;
```

Comment: Thanks, Manjit, but I copied/pasted your code and still got the same error.

Comment: Actually you have to change one line. I have not added the correction in the code. Please look at the last 4 line. The code I wrote is only formatted version of your code

Comment: I meant that I copied/pasted the one line of corrected code and updated my code with it: var CES = 'Please sign this[Company]'
Still getting the same error, though. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out and let you know. Best, Brooks

Comment: Works great! Thank you, Manjit. Clearly I'm a rookie. What did you mean by "ENTER presses"?

Comment: It means that an enter(\r\n) was pressed after this line `"/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID= ` which was causing the error.

Comment: Thank you, Manjtt! How were you able to determine this so I can check on my own in the future and not bother developers on this forum?

Comment: Hover over the button and then right click and select inspect element. Just Above the button you will find a script tag. Expant it and see what is written in eval() function. You may mark this as accepted if it solved your problem.